# in-place vector construction from initialization list (for class with constructor arguments)

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, initializer-list

> *Possible Duplicate:*
>   [Can I list-initialize a vector of move-only type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468774/can-i-list-initialize-a-vector-of-move-only-type)

*Edit 1: Please consider a re-open vote: My question emphasize in-place construction. Move construction is an alternative but not what this questions is about. Thanks for the answers!*

*Edit 2: Since I can't answer this question (It got closed) I post my own suggestion here. The following is not as good as the answers I accepted, but may be useful for others. At least only the move constructor is called:*

```
std::vector<A2> vec;
{
  std::array<A2,3> numbers{{{2,3},{5,6},{7,8}}};
  vec.reserve(numbers.size());
  for (auto &v: numbers) vec.emplace_back(std::move(v)) ;
}
```

**Original post:**

When thinking about the answer to this question: [Initialization of classes within an STL array of vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147935/initialization-of-classes-within-an-stl-array-of-vectors/13148028#13148028) I found that I could not find a way to get in-place construction of the vector from an initialization list. What am I missing?

Now trying to be more clear, I would like this (perfectly correct) initialization

```
std::vector<A2> k{{2,3},{4,5},{8,9}};
```

to have an effect more similar to this:

```
  std::vector<A2> k2;
  k2.reserve(3);
  k2.emplace_back(2,3);
  k2.emplace_back(4,5);
  k2.emplace_back(8,9);
```

However, in the first case the *copy* constructor is called for A2 on a temporary while inserting. Is there a way to avoid that? What does the standard say?

I desperately tried

```
std::vector<A2> k{{2,3},{4,5},std::move(A2{8,9})};
```

but that generates an *additional* call to the move constructor, something I also did not expect. I just wanted to explicitly hint that A2 is a temporary, something I had thought was implied.

Full example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct A2 {
  int mk;
  int mj;
  A2(int k,int j) : mk(k),mj(j) {
    std::cout << "     constr for "<<this<< ":"<< mk<<std::endl;
  }
  A2(const A2& a2) {
    mk=a2.mk;
    mj=a2.mj;    
    std::cout << "copy constr for "<<this<< ":" << mk<<std::endl;
  }
  A2(A2&& a2) noexcept  {
    mk=std::move(a2.mk);
    mj=std::move(a2.mj);
    std::cout << "move constr for "<<this<< ":"<< mk<<std::endl;
  }
};

struct Ano {
  Ano() {
    std::cout << "     constr for "<<this <<std::endl;
  }
  Ano(const Ano& ano) {
    std::cout << "copy constr for "<<this<<std::endl;
  }
  Ano(Ano&& ano) noexcept  {
    std::cout << "move constr for "<<this<<std::endl;
  }
};


int main (){
  // here both constructor and copy constructor is called:
  std::vector<A2> k{{2,3},{4,5},std::move(A2{8,9})};

  std::cout << "......"<<std::endl;
  std::vector<A2> k2;
  k2.reserve(3);
  // here (naturally) only constructor is called:
  k2.emplace_back(2,3);
  k2.emplace_back(4,5);
  k2.emplace_back(8,9);

  std::cout << "......"<<std::endl;  
  // here only constructor is called:
  std::vector<Ano> anos(3);

}
```

Output:

```
     constr for 0xbf9fdf18:2
     constr for 0xbf9fdf20:4
     constr for 0xbf9fdf0c:8
move constr for 0xbf9fdf28:8
copy constr for 0x90ed008:2
copy constr for 0x90ed010:4
copy constr for 0x90ed018:8
......
     constr for 0x90ed028:2
     constr for 0x90ed030:4
     constr for 0x90ed038:8
......
     constr for 0x90ed048
     constr for 0x90ed049
     constr for 0x90ed04a
```

Comment: I think the first constructor is constructing _the initialization list_, which the vector then perfectly move-constructs from.  I'm not certain, but it makes sense.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, I'm after in-place initialization. Move construction would be a second option. True, the top answer to that question helps in explaining what is going on. That does not mean that the questions are the same.

Comment: @JohanLundberg: If you can't move-initialize a vector with an initializer list, you *certainly* can't emplace-initialize it with one.

Comment: I think [initializer_list and move semantics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193102/initializer-list-and-move-semantics) explains a little better about the possible rationale (although I find the current behavior unintuitive).

Comment: why do you want to avoid move construction? the emplace solution too requires a move constructor or copy constructor (if the former is throwing) to be accessible, even if it is not called.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, Thanks, yes I knew that. There's nothing deeper to my question: Just think of a class holding a large array private member on the stack or anything else that can not be *efficiently* copied (or moved). Perhaps not that common...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List-initializing `std::vector` in your snippet is no different from doing the following (if `initializer_list` had a public non-explicit constructor or `std::vector` accepted an array reference.):

```
// directly construct with the backing array of 'initializer_list'
std::vector<A2> v(alias<A2[]>{ A2(2,3), A2(4,5), A2(8,9) });
```

It's not a special way to construct a `std::vector` that could take advantage of the implementation, really. List-initialization is a general-purpose way of "uniformly" initializing types. As such, there's no way it could tread `std::vector` any different than any other user-defined type. As such, having the construct in the OP do emplace construction is out of question.

Now, the backing array (or any constant array) may be put in read-only memory by the implementation, that's the reason why

```
std::initializer_list<T>::iterator
```

is just

```
typedef T const* iterator;
```

So moving out of `std::initializer_list` is also out of question.

Now, is there a solution? Yes, there is, and it's a rather easy one, actually!

We will want to have a free function that takes a container and a number of tuples equal to the number of elements you want to emplace. The tuples container the arguments to the constructor of the container type. Easy in theory, easy in practice with the [indices trick](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks%3aindices) (where `indices == seq` and `build_indices == gen_seq` in the code):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template<class T> using alias = T;
template<class T> using RemoveRef = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;

template<class C, unsigned... Is, class Tuple>
void emplace_back_one(C& c, seq<Is...>, Tuple&& ts){
  c.emplace_back(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(ts))...);
}

template<class T> using Size = std::tuple_size<RemoveRef<T>>;

template<class C, class... Tuples>
void emplace_back(C& c, Tuples&&... ts){
  c.reserve(sizeof...(Tuples));
  alias<char[]>{(
    emplace_back_one(c, gen_seq<std::tuple_size<RemoveRef<Tuples>>::value>{}, std::forward<Tuples>(ts))
  , '0')...};
}
```

[Live example with the implementation of `seq` and `gen_seq`.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/b2b488cba1b266729afa03d1d24fecac)

The code above calls `emplace_back_one` exactly `sizeof...(Tuples)` times, passing one tuple at a time in the order that the were passed to `emplace_back`. This code is also sequenced left-to-right, meaning that the constructors get called in the same order that you passed the tuples for them. `emplace_back_one` then simply unpacks the tuple with the indices trick and passes the arguments to `c.emplace_back`.

Comment: The whole point of the intializer list mechanism is that it's *readable*. If you're going to have this list of `forward_as_tuple` stuff, one forwarding call for each element, you may as well just have a series of `emplace_back` statements. At least that's *shorter*.

Comment: @NicolBolas, yes but this writes those emplace_back calls automatically, compile time, so why not? In practice I would probably just iterate at run-time, assuming construction is significantly more expensive than the loop and argument passing.

Comment: @JohanLundberg: "*yes but this writes those emplace_back calls automatically, compile time, so why not?*" Because it takes up more physical space in code than a series of `v.emplace_back` calls.

Comment: @Nicol: Sure, the current form might be a bit verbose, but you can always tinker with Boost.Preprocessor and then write `EMPLACE_BACK(v, (1,2)(3,4)(5,6))`, which shouldn't be too hard to do actually. :) Also, in generic code, where you might already have those tuples, I think it's pretty nice to have. Also, if you don't have temporaries or want to specifically move stuff into the elements, you can use `std::tie`, which is a lot less verbose.

Comment: @Xeo: Your link no longer works. Could you republish the full example?

Answer (score 12):

Construction of an object via `std::initializer_list` is no different than constructing an object from any other *object*. The `std::initializer_list` is not a mystical, phantasmal construct; it is a living, breathing C++ object (albeit a temporary one). As such, it obeys all the rules of regular living, breathing C++ objects.

Aggregate initialization can effectively elide the copy/moves because it's aggregate initialization, a purely compile-time construct. `std::vector` is many things; an aggregate and a purely compile-time construct are not among them. So, in order for it to initialize itself from what it is given, it must execute actual C++ code, not compile-time stuff. It must iterate over each element of the `initializer_list` and either copy those values or move them. And the latter is not possible, since `std::initializer_list` doesn't provide non-`const` access to its members.

Initializer list initialization is meant to *look* like aggregate initialization, not perform like it. That's the cost of having a runtime, dynamic abstraction like `std::vector`.

Comment: Aggregate initialization is not a compile-time construct, really. `std::array<std::vector<int>, 3> a{{ {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6} }};` will for sure require runtime constructor calls and dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Xeo: But only because there's a non-aggregate in the middle of it. It stops being aggregate initialization once you get into the `vector`.