# C++ - construct vector of unique_ptr via initialization list

Tags: c++, initialization, polymorphism, initializer-list

I have a class, called `group`, that shall keep a number of base classes inside it, held in `std::unique_ptr`s (polymorphism). The order does not matter, nor does if some of the elements are equal between them. It's a task for a `std::vector`, that I would ideally flag as `const` in the member declaration.

As part of the design, I would like to pass all the elements that will fit into the `group` object in an `initializer_list`, like this:

```
class base;

class derived1 : base;
class derived2 : base;
class derived3 : base;

group my_object({ new derived1() , new derived2() , new derived3() });
```

But I'm having trouble with the following:

- The vector inside the `group` class will be made up of `std::unique_ptr`, **not** objects.
- As `std::initializer_list`s may only hold objects of **one type**, that type shall be a pointer-to-base-class.

Taking all that into account, how should I implement it? As the elements held in the `group` class' vector are not supposed to change, it's much more efficient to initialize it in the initialization list of the constructor. However, `std::unique_ptr`s are not copyable, and I can't figure out how to construct a `vector` of `unique_ptr<base_class>` from an `initializer_list` made up of raw pointers.

Comment: @jrok Sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: *"it's much more efficient to initialize it in the initialization list of the constructor"* -- Are you sure? Is it really more efficient than calling `reserve()` on the vector, then calling push_back/emplace_back for each pointer?  The source code might be more aesthetically pleasing, but I doubt you would notice a difference in efficiency.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I list-initialize a vector of move-only type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468774/can-i-list-initialize-a-vector-of-move-only-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an initialization list like this:

```
#include<memory>

class base{};

class derived1 : public base{};
class derived2 : public base{};;
class derived3 : public base{};;

using namespace std;
int main (){
  auto ptrs={ unique_ptr<base>(new derived1()) , unique_ptr<base>(new derived2()) , unique_ptr<base>(new derived3()) };

}
```

But the problem seems to be that you can not move from that initializer list since initializer lists are constant. There is more on this here. [initializer_list and move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193102/initializer-list-and-move-semantics)

I asked a related but different question at [in-place vector construction from initialization list (for class with constructor arguments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148772/in-place-vector-construction-from-initialization-list-for-class-with-constructo/13150599#13150599)

Comment: But how would I handle that in the constructor of my `group` class? How can I tell the constructor of a `vector` to take the objects inside an `initializer_list` and *move* them?

Comment: initializer_lists are constant. they just can not be moved from.